# Excel Randomly crash after executing Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I am tearing my hair out on this one.

I am trying to add the value from a userform textbox to a table.

However Excel is constantly crashing on me as soon as it runs the code below.

The error message i get is

> runtime error -2147417848 "Method 'Value'of object 'Range' failed

then excel crashes

I have tried Option explicit to check i wasnt missing a variable or it was declared incorrectly, i have tried deleting the table and starting again, i have started a new workbook, i have change the table name, i have tried 4/5 different methods of adding the data to the table (Simple range offset, databodyrange(X,1), resizing the table etc). All crash when adding the value (which by the way is just text like mike/harry etc)

The workbook, has about 10 forms and they all work perfectly (they add data to tables etc), it is just this one causing issues

If i manually add data to the table it auto extends and have no issues

any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Enterprise_Update()
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Set lst = Sheets("Data Labels").ListObjects("Enterprises")


    For Each ctrl In Enterprise_Setup.Controls
        If ctrl.Name Like "Enterprise Name Value 1*" Then
            z = z + 1
        End If
    Next ctrl

    With lst.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .Apply
    End With


    With lst
        LstRw = .ListRows.Count
    End With


    Select Case LstRw

    Case Is = 1

        lst.DataBodyRange(LstRw, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = Enterprise_Setup.Controls("Enterprise Name Value 1" & x)

    Case Else

        For x = 1 To z

            sLookFor = CStr(Enterprise_Setup.Controls("Enterprise Name Value 1" & x))

            Set oLookin = lst.DataBodyRange
            Set oFound = oLookin.Find(what:=sLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)


            If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
                GoTo err:

            Else
                With lst
                    LstRw = .ListRows.Count
                End With
            End If

            r = Enterprise_Setup.Controls("Enterprise Name Value 1" & x).Value

            Sheets("Data Labels").Select
            Range(lst.Range.Cells(1).Address).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = r
            'lst.DataBodyRange(X).Value = r

        err:
            Next
    End Select
    With lst.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Enterprises[Enterprises]"), Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the macro code and stepped through to see the line which is causing the crash?

Comment: yes it is the `activecell.value =r`

Comment: is Range(lst.Range.Cells(1).Address).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
not selecting an entire column, therefore Active cell is not a single cell, but a range? Hence your error?

Comment: Hi Simon, no, it selects the header row of the table, and then xldown.offset etc. It goes to the correct cell. This "Version" of code is just the latest, all versions do the correct thing, it is just that excel keeps crashing at the line that sets the cell value.

Comment: I think my next step would be to review what r and activeCell.value is at that point. Make sure r has been set correctly? See what is exactly trying to be set and into where.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this portion of your code and have some comments on it.

```
        If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
            GoTo err
        Else
            LstRw = Lst.ListRows.Count
        End If

        r = Enterprise_Setup.Controls("Enterprise Name Value 1" & x).Value
        Sheets("Data Labels").Select
        Range(Lst.Range.Cells(1).Address).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = r
```

For one, `GoTo err`? `Err` is VBA's error object. VBA is very good at avoiding errors from intrusions on its naming prerogative but I still think its asking for trouble. Note that the final colon is required to identify the label but not the destination statement.

Using labels to jump back and forth in the code isn't good practice. Nor is it needed in this case. A simple `If Not oFound Is Nothing Then` should do the job if you extend the `End If` to the point where you have the label. Anyway, what's the point of `LstRw = Lst.ListRows.Count`? You took that measure before the Select Case statement. Has it changed?

But most of all, I question why you would jump if you found what you were looking for and process when you didn't. This is the best candidate for the error you see.

Selecting another sheet is not good practice and not required, either. You can read from and write to the sheet without selecting it. If you are selecting the sheet from a user form Excel might consider this cause for divorce. Of course, selecting a cell is equally unnecessary.

`Range(Lst.Range.Cells(1).Address).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` probably works, although I think it's adventurous. But selecting that cell may be problematic when done from within a user form. The form sort of claims right of first attention. I doubt that you can activate that cell from where you are.

You can write to it,  however. `Sheets("Data Labels").Cells(54, "A").Value = r` would be a great success, I feel confident. The contortions you undertake to describe the cell's coordinates aren't necessary. The column seems to be `Lst.Range.Column` and the row would be `Lst.Range.Row + LstRw` or perhaps `Lst.DataBodyRange.Row + LstRw`.

However, there might be additional problems resulting from the location of the cell in a table or just under a table where adding a row might create conflict with data existing there. If the table is required to expand as a result of writing to that cell Excel would normally just over-write whatever might exist but it's a point worth considering if all other options have been exhausted.

I hope this analysis will help you find and correct the error.

Comment: Thanks Variatus, I think my code didnt copy in correctly as the semi colon is in there. It take your point on jumping around, and will look at it, but it works perfectly for my scenario for now. as for the lstrw, yes it can change if the user is adding more than one row at a time. Selecting another sheet - completely agree, this is my code after trying all other normal syntax for getting to the row i want to add data too, which still didnt work, so yes not best practice. There is no issue with table location as a table next to it, can be added/deleted from without issue. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by a less than pretty way. I managed to extend the table, and code around the blank rows, ie count none blanks, dynamic named ranges etc